# Echo .csv data to a file

Tags: php, sql, bash, csv

I am trying to echo SQL output stored in a variable in to a .csv file using:

```
sql=$(sqlplus -s $user/$pass@$db << EOF
SELECT DISTINCT id, customer
FROM orders;
exit;
EOF
)

echo $sql > tmp.csv
```

When I open the .csv the output is all on a single line?

Using `SPOOL` in SQL*Plus is not an option, need some way of doing it like above.

How do I get this to appear as a .csv, not on a single line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use double quotes in shell variable:

```
echo "$sql" > tmp.csv
```

Without quotes all newlines are converted into spaces.